# template name in twig main layout

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Is it possible in **twig** to get the name of the child template in the layout?
For Example when calling:

```
$app['twig']->render('index.twig');
```

then in *layout.twig*, which is the main layout, it should ask:

```
if page is index.twig => include this javascript
```

I could do this with additional variables in the render call, but this seems to be bloated since the template name would indicate it already.

Comment: i think this issue is pretty much the same: https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/350

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking at this the wrong way. Imagine if you had a lot of views, then you'd have to do that for each one:

```
{% if _self.getTemplateName() == 'index.twig' %}
    <script src="{{ asset('somescript1') }}"></script>
{% endif %}
{% if _self.getTemplateName() == 'members.twig' %}
    <script src="{{ asset('somescript2') }}"></script>
{% endif %}
{% if _self.getTemplateName() == 'news.twig' %}
    <script src="{{ asset('somescript3') }}"></script>
{% endif %}
...
```

I find this approach pretty bad. What you can do, in your main layout file (lets assume its 'layout.html.twig' for this example) is make a block:

```
{% block javascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

Then, in your view files:

```
{% extends 'AcmeHelloBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

....
{% block javascripts %}
<script src="asset('index.js')"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Basically, you're overriding the block inside your layout file with new contents. In case you had anything inside your 'layout.html.twig' (like for example jquery), you'd also have to call parent():

```
{% extends 'AcmeHelloBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

....
{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
<script src="asset('index.js')"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

`parent()` just makes sure to copy all of the contents from the parent block too.

Comment: The usage is changed to `_self.getTemplateName()`.

Comment: Note that this returns a `Twig_Markup` object. If you strictly need a string, then use `_self.getTemplateName().__toString`.